# Codeigniter update record

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an update record that looks like this

```
$data_gallery = array(
'order' => $value
);

$this->db->where('order', $newOrder);
$this->db->update('gallery', $data_gallery);
```

I have say, 5 images I have reorderd. I have their old position and their new position.

But as I loop through they sometime overwrite each other.

Example:

5 images 1,2,3,4,5

I change the order 2,1,3,4,5

I update in the loop as it goes through the array of new order.

```
Update order = 2 where order = 1
Update order = 1 where order = 2
```

Obviously the second one never gets hit as order = 2 no longer exits.

I guess this more a logic question than anything else.

Any ideas how I can easily loop through and update without losing some of the data? I though maybe updating in a batch operation but didn't get very far with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why update order WHERE order? Maybe it is better to use record id, rather?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the image's ID in your WHERE clause:

```
$this->db->where('imageid', $imageid);
```

This will set the new order to each image without previously overwriting (and disappearing!) any information.

Comment: I thought the same thing after coming back to it with a fresh set of eyes this evening. Working a treat now.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have any other fields to check for your criteria to match the exact records.

```
$data_gallery = array(
   'order' => $value
);

$this->db->where('order', $newOrder);
//check if you have any other fields to match also image id, record id or any other ids to match
$this->db->where('second_id',$second_id);
$this->db->update('gallery', $data_gallery);
```